# How does cygwin's "-mwindows" switch work in windows 7?

Tags: winapi, windows-7, cygwin, windows-xp

I am building an FLTK application in Windows XP under cygwin.

When I pass "-mwindows" to the linker, it behaves as advertized, and I don't get the command window popping up. However, when i run the same application under windows 7, a black console window pops up as if I hadn't passed -mwindows! does anyone know how i can debug this problem?

Thanks,
Woody

Comment: Are you using Cygwin 1.7? Windows 7 required a special workaround to avoid a console popup, which isn't present in earlier Cygwin versions.

Comment: That was it; i was using a too-old version of cygwin. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ak2 was right, i needed to update Cygwin.